# Python loop explanation

Tags: python, loops

I'm learning from official Python tutorial and came to the point where i cannot understand, why all of a sudden, an X became 3. Please check the code below:

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         if n % x == 0:
...             print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
...             break
...     else:
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
...         print(n, 'is a prime number')
...
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3
```

When loop comes to `n = 9`, why `x = 3` and not `x = 2` ???? So, when loop came to the point where `x = 3`? My logic would be; if `n = 9` then `9 is a prime number`(although it is not) because `x = 2`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `x = 2` was handled but didn't hit your condition, since 2 doesn't divide 9. Try putting in a `print(x)` in the beginning of the loop if you're unsure how it's handled. Also, 9 isn't a prime.

Comment: I know 9 isn't a prime, but i thought 9 should be in that place  since it did't hit the first contition! Will try to print!

Comment: It only prints out `x is a prime number` once it has exhausted all of the possible divisors.

Comment: I get it!!!!! Thank you so much!:))

Comment: @Kuki Please avoid placing things like *beginner level* since they contribute nothing to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a construct called the for-else loop.  The else block will be executed if the for loop runs to completion without calling `break`.  If you look again, you will see that the else is indented to the same level as the for, not the if.

So every value of `x` is checked before declaring n to be prime.